# FullText search query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I've the following Table Structure:

```
id           bigint(20)
loc          text   
lastmod      datetime
changefreq   varchar(15)
priority     float
isdownloaded tinyint(1)
mainrepoid   bigint(20)
```

FullText is enabled on loc having links, I want to extract all the links having both 'name' and 'details' words but should not include 'character' word. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE MATCH (
   loc
)
AGAINST (
   'name+details-character'
)
```

But the returned results also have 'character' word in them. In short I actually want all the urls with this structure example.com/**name**/id/**details** from the loc field.

Comment: Put spaces between those words, like: 'name +details -character'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jauzsika said in the comment, you should put spaces between it.

If "name" **must** be present, you should also add a plus in front of it.

Furthermore; these operators only work in boolean mode. You should add IN BOOLEAN MODE to your AGAINST-statement, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE MATCH (
   loc
)
AGAINST (
   '+name +details -character' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

Comment: I actually want all the urls with this structure http://www.example.com/name/id/details from the loc field.

Comment: Although the above will work just fine, I'd rather go for a like in this case: WHERE loc LIKE '%example.com/name/id/details%'

Answer (score 0):

Also you should check system vars `ft_max_word_len` and `ft_min_word_len` because fulltext search may skip some records depending on word's length.

[sys vars](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_max_word_len)